# Using XNA content pipeline with SharpDX game for Windows Phone 8

Tags: windows-phone-8, windows-phone, sharpdx, content-pipeline

I've decided to try out SharpDX for my first Windows Phone game but I'm having troubles setting up Content Pipeline working.

I have tried creating an XNA Content Project and dummy XNA Game Library project (just to reference Content project from) but I've got `SharpDX.Toolkit.Content.AssetNotFoundException` when I tried to load a texture.

Second try was to use [XNA 4.0 Content Compiler](http://xnacontentcompiler.codeplex.com/) to get .xnb file and add it manually to my project but again I've got `AssetNotFoundException`.

The `Content.RootDirectory` is set to correct value (`"Content"`, the name of an XNA Content Project in first try, and a name of folder containing .xnb file in second try), so that's probably not an issue.

So, the real question is, how to load a Texture2D from file in SharpDX project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SharpDX Toolkit is not a XNA compatible API/implementation, and thus, is not able to load XNA content. It is a high level API for Direct3D11, with some XNA like interfaces/features (SpriteBatch, BasicEffect, ContentManager...etc.) but not binary compatible with XNA. If you want to work with legacy XNA projects, you will have to use a library like MonoGame

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried to create Windows Phone 8 project using MonoGame project template? MonoGame make it a lot easier to create XNA game on WP8 (it uses SharpDX under the cover). You can download the latest framework from here: http://monogame.codeplex.com/releases/view/102870

Comment: Thanks for answering. I should have stated that I am considering switching to MonoGame but I would really like to know what I was doing wrong :)